# There is a variable in scope. Is it undefined behavior to use this variable address outside of scope?

Tags: c++, memory, scope

Here is a simple example.

```
void func()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    if(p == nullptr)
    {
        int n;
        p = &n;
    }
    *p = 10; // undefined behavior??
}
int main()
{
    func();
}
```

There is no complie warning(visual studio 2019), is it "undefined behavior" to use "* p = 10" in this way?

Can it vary by compiler or by debug or release?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Comment: "_is undefined behavior?_" Yes.

Comment: what the program will do can differ by compiler and by the phase of the moon, but it is always undefined

Comment: @NikosC. You're going to have to enlighten me on that one.

Comment: Oops, misread the code... Sorry.

Comment: @NikosC.: Phew, I thought I had a huge refactoring job tomorrow.

Comment: fwiw, the edit didnt change anything on the question or on the answer. When your code has UB the compiler is not required to issue a warning or error

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the behaviour on dereferencing `p` is undefined.

Note also that the behaviour of even **reading** `p` once the object to which it points is out of scope is problematic: at this point it is an *invalid pointer value*, and formally the behaviour of reading `p` is *implementation-defined*, which can include a system generated runtime fault.

This latter point is often overlooked.

Comment: It's easy to misread your answer. I first thought that "dereferencing and reading" were the same because I mixed up n and p. Maybe you could write: reading p is already undefined behavior, even without dereferencing it. This would mention the actions in their chronological order and this be simpler to understand.

Comment: After the pointed-to object is destroyed the pointer does not behave as if it was uninitialized, i.e. as an *indeterminate value*. Rather it will become an *invalid pointer value*. Evaluating *indeterminate values* has undefined behavior, evaluating *invalid pointer values* has *implementation-defined behavior*, so in practice it would probably be fine on most platforms. (Ideally one should be able to find the behavior in the compiler documentation, but I am not sure that any compiler documents this properly.) See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc-4 and [DR 616](https://wg21.link/cwg616)

Comment: @walnut Interesting difference: Likely because the value of a pointer to an object which has gone out of scope has at least a valid address format, in particular it is not a trap value.